# Oracle SQL Syntax: Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Are the following sql statement valid in Oracle SQL?

1)

```
select 1
```

2)

```
select test from (select 1 as test)
```

3)

```
select test from (select 1 as test) s
```

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of them are valid. These are the correct statements:

1)

```
select 1 from dual
```

2)

```
select test from (select 1 as test from dual)
```

3)

```
select test from (select 1 as test from dual) s
-- or also
select s.test from (select 1 as test from dual) s
```